# xamarin when call button inside listview gives "does not exist in current context"

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

hey guys i've issue to call my button inside the listview i solved it by event click and down cast it , but i want to change some properties on "button 1" when i click on "button 2"
my code in xaml :

```
<Button Clicked="SetLike" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="{Binding Likes}" Image="{Binding likeimg}" />
<Button Clicked="SetDisLike" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="{Binding Dislikes}" Image="{Binding dislikeimg}" />
```

when i give the button a name `x:Name=""` it gives me

> "does not exist in current context xamarin list"

here in the back i want to change the "button 1" properties when call "button 2" but i couldn't make it because i'm not able to access the nasted item inside my listview:

```
public void SetDisLike (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var b = (Button)sender;
Joke t = (Joke)b.CommandParameter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i made it by giving the contentpage a name "page" and assign my path to its bindingcontext

```
Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=Page}, Path=BindingContext.AddLike}"
```